# Can you do .prev() minus a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of buttons and you can navigate them using the left and right arrow keys, but im trying to implement up and down key presses aswell but adding .prev(-3) doesnt seems to work, so I was just wondering if its possible to do that?

I have setup a test of what im doing [here](https://jsbin.com/xesamifida/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
            $("button:focus").next().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            $("button:focus").prev().focus();

        }

      if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
            $("button:focus").next(+3).focus();

        }
      if (e.keyCode == 38) {      
            $("button:focus").prev(-3).focus();

        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I suppose you could do `.prev().prev().prev()` but that seems messy.

Comment: Maybe you could get the index number of the currently focused button (via `.index()`) and use that?

Comment: you could use a combination of `nextAll` and `eq`: `$("button:focus").nextAll().eq(2)`

Comment: @Pete has the right idea. `.prevAll().eq(2)` works as well, since `prevAll` gives elements in "reverse" order (that is, closest to the current element first)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that works great, but could i ask you one more thing? how does this work with seperate divs? it currently stops at the last button in the current div. How would it work but crossing over into all divs with buttons in? see this example https://jsbin.com/xesamifida/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 4):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/998/)**.

I would use `nextAll` and `prevAll` in combination with `eq`:

```
$("button:focus")
  .nextAll() // get all following siblings
  .eq(2);    // get third from the set (zero based)


$("button:focus")
  .prevAll() // get all previous siblings
  .eq(2);    // get third from the set (zero based)
```

Comment: that works great, but could i ask you one more thing? how does this work with seperate divs? it currently stops at the last button in the current div. How would it work but crossing over into all divs with buttons in? see this example jsbin.com/xesamifida/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: it there no way to cross over divs?

Comment: I guess you would have to get the full collection of all buttons, filter out the focused one and get it's index in the collection, then just use eq for plus or minus three from the current index, but that's a completely different question to the one you have asked

Answer (score 0):

Prev(number) is not supported by jquery but you can call it multiple times, see below code

```
$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
            $("button:focus").next().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            $("button:focus").prev().focus();

        }

      if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
            $("button:focus").next().next().next().focus();

        }
      if (e.keyCode == 38) {      
            $("button:focus").prev().prev().prev().focus();

        }
    }
);
```

**[working Code](https://jsbin.com/qopiqimazu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

Answer (score 0):

i used to do like this but i changed to this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/cqpj10my/)

I prefer to use `tabindex`

1. i count my buttons, input, select
2. i add to them tabindex by each
3. last i focus it by its index

```js
let el=$('button');
for(var i = 1; i<=el.length; i++){
  el.eq(i-1).attr('tabindex',i);
} 

$('button').unbind().on('keydown', function(event) {
  let currentTabIndex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
  let el = $('button');
  switch (event.which) {
    case 38:
      currentTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabIndex) - 1;
      if (currentTabIndex == 0) {
        $("[tabindex=" + el.length + "]").focus()
      } else {
        $("[tabindex=" + currentTabIndex + "]").focus()
      }
      break;
    case 13:
    case 40:
      currentTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabIndex) + 1;
      if (currentTabIndex == el.length+1) {
        $("[tabindex=" + 1 + "]").focus()
      } else {
        $("[tabindex=" + currentTabIndex + "]").focus()
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
button:focus{
  border:1px solid red;
  background:yellow; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button> 
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button> 
<button>6</button>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button> 
<button>9</button>
```

all you need is select your buttons good on **selecter**